# Aws how to read cloudwatch graph?

Tags: linux, monitoring, amazon-ec2, aws

I have one instance on AWS and here is the graph from cloudwatch but those Network (in) and Network (out)? How do i calculate how much bandwidth my instance eating? They are in `Bytes`

[image]